# How to change controls on a Windows form without changing the form itself

Tags: c#, .net

What I am trying to remember is the name of a windows form control which allows with an ID change allows programmer to move between its states, which are different panels with different controls on them. There is a control that does exactly this - but I can't remember its name at all. Do you know anything similar to this in C#?

edit: basically, I have a windows form. It has a panel. I want to, by changing panel's a specific property, I want to switch between its states, every state containing another set of windows form controls. I cannot, however, remember the name of this control. Any ideas? Sorry if my first wording is confusing.

Comment: TabControl?  Question is a little confusing, you might want to consider rewording some.

Comment: I reworded it, should be a little more clear. sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you mean something like a wizard? In asp.net [webforms has a wizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx) buy afaik the closest in windows forms is TabControl. But no matter; it is trivial to simply hide and show some Panel controls. It can be trickier to use the designer, of course - but you can lay them out next to each other and move then at runtime as needed.

Comment: Yeah, I'm basically trying to find an equivalent of wizard control. I agree, but if there was a wizard I thought it could be a little bit more elegant. You're probably right, It seems I'm misremembering an asp.net control as a windows forms control. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there are a few wizards available for WinForms too

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195255/best-wizard-control-for-net-windows-forms

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WizardDemo.aspx

And, well, [plenty of others](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=windows+forms+weizard&btnG=Google+Search&aq=undefined&oq=windows+forms+weizar#hl=en&pwst=1&sa=X&ei=vvNfTYj9LomgsQPpqrTCCA&ved=0CBgQvwUoAQ&q=windows+forms+wizard&spell=1&bav=on.1,or.&fp=681127d0c6f645aa)